# Rails: Overriding ActiveRecord association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, overriding

Is there a way to override one of the methods provided by an ActiveRecord association?

Say for example I have the following typical polymorphic has_many :through association:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings, :order => :name
end


class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :stories, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Story"
end
```

As you probably know this adds a whole slew of associated methods to the Story model like tags, tags<<, tags=, tags.empty?, etc.

How do I go about overriding one of these methods? Specifically the tags<< method. It's pretty easy to override a normal class methods but I can't seem to find any information on how to override association methods. Doing something like

```
def tags<< *new_tags
    #do stuff
end
```

produces a syntax error when it's called so it's obviously not that simple.

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? This could end up breaking other ActiveRecord functionality, and there's probably a better way to do what you're trying

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use block with `has_many` to extend your association with methods. See comment "Use a block to extend your associations" [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#461-User-a-block-to-extend-your-associations).
Overriding existing methods also works, don't know whether it is a good idea however.

```
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings, :order => :name do
    def << (value)
      "overriden" #your code here
      super value
    end     
  end
```

Comment: Of course!  Forgot about that one.  This is probably the best way to do what you are after.

Comment: And how would you call the original method?
(I want to override the build method, add some defaults and then call the original)

Comment: How can I override association getter this way?

Comment: :-| They could have used RSA, that's a better way of keeping people out of doing this.

Comment: I have tried it with rails 5.1 and it doesnt work for some reason. the overriding function is not called

Answer (score 19):

If you want to access the model itself in Rails 3.2 you should use `proxy_association.owner`

Example:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books do
    def << (book)
      proxy_association.owner.add_book(book)
    end
  end

  def add_book (book)
    # do your thing here.
  end
end
```

See [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions)

Comment: this is still the case in Rails 5.1

Comment: @coconup this does not work for me in rails 5.1 - the overriding << method is not called at all :-(

Answer (score 1):

The method I use is to extend the association. You can see the way I handle 'quantity' attributes here: https://gist.github.com/1399762

It basically allows you to just do

```
has_many : tags, :through => : taggings, extend => QuantityAssociation
```

Without knowing exactly what your hoping to achieve by overriding the methods its difficult to know if you could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted `def tags.<<(*new_tags)` for the signature, which should work, or the following which is equivalent and a bit cleaner if you need to override multiple methods.

```
class << tags
  def <<(*new_tags)
    # rawr!
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think either of those will work.  It looks like you what you are suggesting is trying to extend the Eigenclass of the value returned by the `tags` method.

Comment: It's defining a method within the eigenclass of whatever is returned by `tags`, which is probably an array. This has the effect of adding a new instance method to the array, which is what I understood the original question to be asking. `extend` has a specific meaning in ruby and that's not what's going on here.

Comment: You are right, that is exactly what it's doing.  I guess I just didn't understand  where you were suggesting to put that code.  Anyway, i guess I answered pretty much the same thing, just with a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define the tags method to return an object which has a `<<` method.

You could do it like this, but I really wouldn't recommend it.  You'd be much better off just adding a method to your model that does what you want than trying to replace something ActiveRecord uses.

This essentially runs the default `tags` method adds a << method to the resulting object and returns that object.  This may be a bit resource intensive because it creates a new method every time you run it

```
def tags_with_append
  collection = tags_without_append
  def collection.<< (*arguments)
    ...
  end
  collection
end
# defines the method 'tags' by aliasing 'tags_with_append'
alias_method_chain :tags, :append
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be helpful in your case but could be useful for others looking into this.

Association Callbacks:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Example from the docs:

```
class Project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :developers, :after_add => :evaluate_velocity

  def evaluate_velocity(developer)
    ...
  end
end
```

Also see Association Extensions:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people do
    def find_or_create_by_name(name)
      first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
      find_or_create_by_first_name_and_last_name(first_name, last_name)
    end
  end
end

person = Account.first.people.find_or_create_by_name("David Heinemeier Hansson")
person.first_name # => "David"
person.last_name  # => "Heinemeier Hansson"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rails guides](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Overriding+generated+methods) documents about overriding the added methods directly.

OP's issue with overriding `<<` probably is the only exception to this, for which follow [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891245/474597). But it wouldn't work for `has_one`'s `=` assignment method or getter methods.