# Is there a way to override the << operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overriding

I'm trying to do something like:

```
account.users << User.new
```

But I need users to be a method on an account. So I've tried things like:

```
def users<<(obj)
```

But I've had no luck with that. Is this even possible to do in Ruby? I would assume so because the ActiveRecord relationships seem to work this way in Rails.

Comment: Is this `users` Rails association?

Answer (score 10):

Check this answer: [Rails: Overriding ActiveRecord association method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890761/rails-overriding-activerecord-association-method)

[this code is completely from the other answer, here for future searchers]

```
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings, :order => :name do
    def << (value)
      "overriden" #your code here
    end     
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you might not be describing your actual problem, but to answer your question -- yes you can override the `<<` operator:

```
class Foo
  def <<(x)
    puts "hi! #{x}"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x00000009b389f0>
> f << "there"
hi! there
```

Comment: I don't want to use the Foo class though. I want to user foo.users << x

Comment: @JohnBaker, `foo.users << obj` is equivalent to `foo.users.send :<<, obj`. You should simply return Foo's array of users; the [`Array#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) method will push additional users into the array.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a model like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

To override `Account#users<<`, you need to define it in a block that you pass to `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users do
    def <<(user)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

You can access the appropriate `Account` object by referring to `proxy_association.owner`:

```
def <<(user)
  account = proxy_association.owner
end
```

To call the original `Account#users<<`, call `Account#users.concat`:

```
def <<(user)
  account = proxy_association.owner
  # user = do_something(user)
  account.users.concat(user)
end
```

For more details, see this page: [Association extensions - ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions)

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's the `<<` of you class of you User. So can be an `Array` or a `AssociationProxy`.

The must simplest is create a new method to do what you want.

You can override the method by instance instead.

```
account.users.instance_eval do
  def <<(x)
    put 'add'
  end
end

account.users << User.new
# add
```

But you need do that all the time before you add by <<

Answer (score 0):

`users` would return an object that has overridden `<<` operator like `Array`, `IO`, `String`, or any type you create. You override like this:

```
class SomeType
  def <<(obj)
    puts "Appending #{obj}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to perform an action upon adding an `User` to the `users` collection, you can use [association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) instead of over-riding `<<`(as there are many ways to add an object to an association).

```
class Account
  has_many :users, :after_add => :on_user_add

  def on_user_add(user)
    p "Added user : #{user.name} to the account: #{name}"
  end
end
```