# Overriding find in Rails model doesn't effect scoped finds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Author model that has_many Books.

I've overridden Books to be able to be found by their title

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base    
...
 def self.find(input)
    if input.is_a?(Integer) || input.integer?
      super(input)
    else
      return Book.find_by_title(input)
    end
  end
...
end
```

This works fine in most cases, but if I do something like `author.books.find("Some Book Title")` this method doesn't seem to be called.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going through the `books` collection, you are actually calling `find` on a [CollectionProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html). You can extend the methods from a `has_many` by passing a block to it like the answer says in this thread: [Rails: Overriding ActiveRecord association method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890761/rails-overriding-activerecord-association-method)