# Rails, override association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Well, I have a model with a has_many association:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
end
```

Now, I know that if I call `foo.bars` it loads all the bars where `foo_id` is `foo.id`, right? But I would like to override it, so that I could load `bars` based on other params..

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516456/7219974) kinda teaches how to override the `<< (value)` method. But yet, I don't know how to apply it in my case.

How could I do that?? Something like this:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars do
    def bars
      self.owner = Bar.where(date: foo.date) #just an example
    end
  end
end
```

???

Comment: Still not really clear what you're trying to do. Do you want the association to be based on, say, `foos.date = bars.date` rather than `foos.bar_id = bars.id`?

Comment: Yeah!! Something like that.. When I call `foo.bars` I want it to return all the bars in a given date instead of all the bars that belongs to `foo`.

Comment: Do you really want a formal association then? Maybe you're just looking for a simple method without all the association machinery.

Comment: Well, I see what you're saying, but I would like to use the other methods from an ActiveRecord association. But thinking better about it know, maybe I would have to override most of the other methods as well. Anyways.. I would like to know how to do this just for curiosity..

Answer (score 3):

You can set a condition on the `has_many` attribute like this

```
has_many :bars, -> { where(active: true) }
```

More on that in [the guides (section 4.3.3)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Well, it does help, thanks!! However, I don't want to extend, because I want to search only the bars with `active: true` not all the bars with `foo_id: foo.id` and that `active: true`. Get me?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Can you perhaps update your question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for a way to override an association getter so that it acts like a simple [scope](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) or [`where` query](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) instead — namely, that you want `foo.bars` to return a set of `bars` that may or may not belong to `foo`.

This is a **huge** red flag.

The whole point of having the `#bars` association getter method as an **instance method** of `Foo` is to return a list of `bars` **related to a single model object**. If you want something different, define the behavior somewhere else.

In theory, what you're asking is possible — just take the `def bars` stanza from your example out of the `has_many` block and put it on the same level as all your other method definitions. But there's simply no sense in it.

`Bar.where` and `scope` are built to do what you're asking about. If you don't want to limit your query to a given `Foo`, then leave `Foo` out of it.